# some css styles not working in component.html but working in index.html

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

After click on UI Element add class (open) ti li, and open collapsed 
but in xxx.component.html not woking

Screenshot

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

If I have to guess your issues, it is most likely that you have your css declared at index component. Angular's css is encapsulated or scoped.

`https://angular.io/guide/component-styles`

Either move your css to styles.css or use read the guide and use `host-cotontext` (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host-context) or disable the encapsulation (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)